# Shell: убийство процесса бесшумно

Tags: linux, bash, shell, php7

Есть PHP скрипт который использует pthreads 3.
Но разработчики удалили функцию kill() для остановки потоков
Скрипт запускается так:
`./bin/php7/bin/php io.php 2> /dev/null` 
Из PHP скрипта, чтобы остановить работу потоков
вызывается команда:
`kill {$pid} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null`
$pid - переменная с pid процесса
Однако на выходе в консоли я получаю раздражающее сообщение:
 
`./start.sh: line 1:   935 Terminated              ./bin/php7/bin/php io.php 928> /dev/null`

Как сделать так чтобы это сообщение не появлялось?
перевод stderr 2> тут не помогает :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sh -c './bin/php7/bin/php io.php 2> /dev/null'`
Нашёл решение...

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите:

```
bash -c 'kill ${pid}' &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Не работает(... 
./start.sh: line 1:  6933 Terminated              ./bin/php7/bin/php io.php 2> /dev/null